# Reported bug with Regular Expression \Q \E in Java 4 & 5

Tags: java, regex

Quoting from [here:](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)

> Java 4 and 5 have bugs that cause \Q…\E to misbehave, however, so you shouldn't use this syntax with Java.

I've made a program which splits Strings up based on given operators, and so I have this as part of my code:

```
Pattern.quote( operator )
```

This program isn't working quite as expected, as it seems its splitting Strings wrong (with the above line being the split's parameter).

When I do this:

```
System.out.println( "Operator:" + Pattern.quote( operator ) );
```

The result is:

> Operator:\Q==\E

This isn't a major issue and I'm still not sure that this line is causing issues. Hence this questions focus is on what the bug mentioned in the Regex is, not what the bug in my program is.

So: what is the bug they mention? I've been unable to find any documentation on such a bug, and hence while we're on Java 8 I'm unsure if this bug has been fixed (I would assume it has been, but I'm still interested none-the-less).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4803197) bug report, that bug (or what seems to be the bug your link was referring to) has been fixed in Java 5, so I would suspect your bug lies elsewhere.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Just what I was looking for. I was more just interested in the bug for the sake of being interested - I agree with you more than likely lies elsewhere.